# Perl - date calculation

Tags: perl

I'm new in Perl. I want to calculate days (e.g. 5 days) after input.

**Steps I need to cover:**
 1. start_date: 08.12.2015
 2. add 5 days
 3. end date: ?

My idea is to convert the start date into a timestamp. Then I add 5*84.400 seconds. After that, I want to re-convert the end timestamp.

I read the `Time::Local` module docs, but I did not understand the logic yet.

Is this the right way to handle date calculations?

Comment: Not every day has 84,400 seconds.

Comment: For my calcs - 84.4K is ok

Comment: You're OK with getting an answer that's not even the right date? Odd, and hardly the case for everyone reading these questions and answers.

Comment: Most days have rather more than 84,400 seconds :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using `DateTime` and `DateTime::Format::Strptime`. Like this:

```
use strict;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => '%d.%m.%Y'
);

my $date = '08.12.2015';
my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime($date);
printf "%s -> %s\n", $date, $dt->add(days => 5)->strftime("%d.%m.%Y");
```

Comment: It works for me. Tx for the edit and the code. You just made my day!

Comment: No problem. I guess that's why this site was made for - developers making each others' day :D

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.10;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $date_string = '08.12.2015';
my $date_format = '%m.%d.%Y';

my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime( $date_string, $date_format );

$tp += 5 * ONE_DAY;

say $tp->strftime($date_format);
```

Outputs:

```
08.17.2015
```

Comment: Works also for me. Tx to you

Answer (score 0):

Or another way, in vanilla perl (no use of packages needed), with help from Unix `date`:

```
$ date -d 08/12/2015
Wed, Aug 12, 2015 12:00:00 AM

$ date -d 08/12/2015 +%s
1439352000

$ date -d 08/12/2015 +%s|perl -ne 'print scalar localtime $_ + 5*24*60*60'
Mon Aug 17 00:00:00 2015
```

Comment: Not every day has 24*60*60 seconds. This won't always give the right answer.